# Volume enclosed by convex surface and tangent plane over a region $\mathcal R$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Consider a convex surface $\mathcal S$ defined by $z = f(x,y)$. The volume between the surface and its tangent plane at point $P$, enclosed within exterior $\mathcal S$ is minimal when $P$ is  the centroid of region $\mathcal R$.

**Note**:There is a region $\mathcal R$ whose outline is any general curve lying along the $xy$-plane, and it extends along the $z$-axis.
For example, if $\mathcal R$ is a circle in the $xy$-plane, extending it along the $z$-axis results in a cylinder, denoted as exterior $\mathcal S$.

I have proven this for $P(x,y) = (0,0)$ when region $\mathcal R$ is a circle of radius $r$, as $P$ is its centroid for any convex surface.

However, I am struggling to prove why this result holds for any convex surface $z = f(x,y)$ and any region $\mathcal R$.

Some of the tools I used to tackle the problem include Lagrange multipliers, the Euler-Lagrange equation, and since the volume under the surface is constant, the problem is equivalent to showing that the volume under the tangent plane at point $P$ is minimum for $P$, where $P$ is the centroid of any region $\mathcal R$ and for any surface $z= f(x,y)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sir please could you answer this question,I have tried a lot but can't reach to conceive reasoning.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Is $\mathcal{R}$ two dimensional or three dimensional ? Either way, how is its centroid guaranteed to be on the surface $\mathcal{S}$ ?? If not, then how do you draw a tangent to a surface at a point that does not exist on the surface ? What does enclosed within the exterior $\mathcal{S}$ mean ? Also, your convex surface is what exactly - the surface of a convex body or is there another definition ?

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding,R is a two dimensional region which lies in xy plane,and there is a point in xy plane such that the volume between surface and tangent plane at that point is minimum,prove that this point is the centroid of 2d region r which lies in xy plane and if the surface is convex,I hope this clear your doubt.

Comment: Tangent plane to what ?? In order to draw a tangent plane at a point, that point must exist on that surface $\mathcal{S}$ in the first place. But you are saying that point belongs to a region $\mathcal{R}$ that has nothing to do with the given surface. 

I recommend that you take a careful look at what you are writing.

Comment: See the special point(x,y,0) is in region r  which lies in xy plane and z=f(x,y) is the equation of surface ,so x,y must be a cordinates of centroid of region r which lies in x y plane such the volume between surface z=f(x,y) and tangent plane to surface z=f(x,y) at cordinate (x,y,f(x,y)) is minimum,i hope now you must be able to understand.

Comment: Then, what you are trying to say is the tangent plane at $\textit{f(P)}$ and your surface is defined as $\mathcal{S} = \{f(x,y)|\,\, (x,y)\in\mathcal{R}\}.$ In other words, you do not just pick any pair of surfaces $(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{R})$, but $\mathcal{S}$ is the image of a map $f:\mathcal{R}\in\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ - i.e., $\mathcal{R}$ is precisely the domain of the function that describes your surface. Is that right ?

Comment: See it's the generalization of Eddie and fritz theorem for 2d function in 3d,and yes you are right now imagine for eg my region is circle and a surface is paraboloid(these are examples),then extending the region r over z axis in this case it turns out to be a cylinder,so the volume between paraboloid and it's tangent plane at point (0,0,f(0,0)) is minimal as (0,0)(all enclosed within the cylinder) is the centroid of the region r which is circle.Note if your region r was square ,extending over z axis it would be cuboid,so we would analyze the volume bounded by surface ,cuboid and tangent plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to clarify what I think the question is:

We have a curve $\mathcal{C}$ in the $xy$ plane, which encloses a region $\mathcal{R}$. Now consider a function $f:\mathcal{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$, defining a surface $S=\{(x,y,f(x,y)\,:\,(x,y)\in\mathcal{R}\}$ lying "above" $\mathcal{R}$, and suppose that the region between the $xy$-plane and $S$ is convex. We will also be interested in the "cylinder" $\mathcal{R}_1=\{(x,y,z)\,:\,(x,y)\in\mathcal{R},z\geq0\}$.

For any point $P=(x,y)\in\mathcal{R}$ we can then find the plane $T_P$ tangent to $S$ at $P$, and we want to choose $P$ to minimize the volume of the region *inside* $\mathcal{R}_1$, *above* $S$, and *below* $T_P$.

Well, we can simplify this a bit: if we add the volume of $S$ to this -- which doesn't change where the minimum is, because the volume of $S$ doesn't depend on $P$ -- then we find we're just looking for the volume of the region inside $\mathcal{R}_1$ and below $T_P$.

If $f(X,Y)=z+a(X-x)+b(Y-y)$ to first order near $(x,y)$ -- so $z=f(x,y)$ and $a,b$ are the first partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x,y)$ -- then $T_P$ is just the plane $Z=z+a(X-x)+b(Y-y)$. Then the volume inside $\mathcal{R}_1$ and below $T_P$ is $\int_\mathcal{R}z+a(X-x)+b(Y-y)\,dx\,dy$.

(I am assuming that the intention is that when the plane $T_P$ goes below the $xy$ plane we include the resulting negative volume.)

We are interested in where this is minimal, so let's think about its derivatives. In order to reduce visual clutter I've written e.g. $f_x$ for $\partial f/\partial x$ and $f_{xy}$ for $\partial^2 f/\partial x\partial y$. I haven't distinguished between $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ because these are equal for well-behaved functions. So, we have

$$V(x,y)=\int_{\mathcal{R}}f(x,y)+f_x(x,y)(X-x)+f_y(x,y)(Y-y)\,dX\,dY$$

and so

$$\begin{eqnarray}
V_x(x,y)&=&\int_{\mathcal{R}}f_x(x,y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl[f_x(x,y)(X-x)\bigr]+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_y(x,y)(Y-y)\,dX\,dY \\
&=&\int_{\mathcal{R}}f_x(x,y)+\bigl[f_{xx}(x,y)(X-x)-f_x(x,y)\bigr]+f_{xy}(x,y)(Y-y)\,dX\,dY \\
&=&\int_{\mathcal{R}}f_{xx}(x,y)(X-x)+f_{xy}(x,y)(Y-y)\,dX\,dY \\
&=&f_{xx}(x,y)\int_{\mathcal{R}}(X-x)\,dX\,dY+f_{xy}(x,y)\int_{\mathcal{R}}(Y-y)\,dX\,dY.
\end{eqnarray}$$

If we write $I=\int_{\mathcal{R}}dX\,dY$ then our centroid's coordinates are $\bar x=\frac1I\int_{\mathcal{R}}X\,dX\,dY$ and $\bar y=\frac1I\int_{\mathcal{R}}Y\,dX\,dY$, so we can rewrite that last line as

$$f_{xx}(x,y)I(\bar x-x)+f_{xy}(x,y)I(\bar y-y).$$

We have a similar expression for $V_y$. So both these partial derivatives will be zero iff

$$\begin{pmatrix}f_{xx}(x,y) & f_{xy}(x,y) \\ f_{xy}(x,y) & f_{yy}(x,y)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\bar x-x\\ \bar y-y\end{pmatrix}=0$$

which, provided our function is *strictly* convex, is true only when $\bar x-x=\bar y-y=0$ because that matrix is negative definite.

Comment: See I am at the beginning level of calc 3 in college like I know jacobian, hessian and fubini theorem and vector calculus only familar with gradiant ,sinosudal vector and all, could you recite some resources where I could learn about tools you used like the last expression A*Integral(X-xdx)=0 and what it represents.

Comment: I've (1) corrected a couple of important errors (which cancelled one another out...), (2) made less attempt to be Clever, and (3) used a different less-clutter-y notation for partial derivatives. Is it easier to follow now?

Comment: Thanks but you also use stokes theorem,could you also tell me about it.

Comment: The reference to Stokes' theorem was in an earlier version of the answer, as a justification for something that isn't actually true :-). But: the "classical" version of Stokes' theorem says that the integral over a _surface_ of the curl of a vector field equals the line integral around the surface's boundary of the vector field itself. The "generalized" version needs the notion of "differential form" [... continues]

Comment: [... continued] and says that if you have a thing $M$ with boundary $\partial M$, and a differential form $\omega$ with (exterior) derivative $d\omega$, then the integrals $\int_Md\omega$ and $\int_{\partial M}\omega$ are equal. Specifically, M is supposed to be a "manifold with boundary", but you can think of it as say a well-behaved subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. And a differential form is "a thing you can take integrals of", and [... continues]

Comment: [... continued] the "exterior derivative" is a thing that generalizes "grad" and "curl" and "div" -- all three of those are just the exterior derivative applied to suitable things. So the "generalized Stokes' theorem" has as special cases (1) the fundamental theorem of calculus, (2) the original Stokes' theorem, (3) the divergence theorem, and (4) Green's theorem about area integrals in 2D.

Comment: Since I think that involves a bunch of ideas you haven''t learned about yet, it may well not make much sense. But it may be of some value to you to have in your head the vague idea that all those things are special cases of a single very general thing, and try to get some sense of what sort of general thing it might be. :-)